How do I get a larger integer than the maximum bitint can provide?
I'm trying to make a simple Fibonacci calculator, but bitints max bit number of 65535 is too small.
Is there any way to get a bigger integer?
typedef unsigned _BitInt(65535) u65535;
int main(void) {
    int n = 99999;
    u65535 a = 1;
    u65535 b = 1;
    u65535 c;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        c=a+b;
        a=b;
        b=c;
        printf("fib: %u\n", a);
    }
    return 0;
} ```


Allocate a buffer of bytes and implement addition.

e.g. int32_t or long

Yes, use a bignum library like gmp, or use a language that provides big integers natively.

I doubt %u is going to work with bitints larger than a normal int width.

You can't set a value larger than  __BITINT_MAXWIDTH__ defined in limits.h, i.e. #define __BITINT_MAXWIDTH__ 128,  65535 is way too long.

@Ibolya Vojtek, "How do I get a larger integer ..." --> Somewhat slow, but one could use strings in a large enough array.  At least useful to check an alternative solution.

On review, OP has identified that 65535 math is too small.  69,430 or so is needed.
We could use 2 bigint digits, like struct { _BitInt(35000) msb, lsb; } and form supporting addition and print routines.   But is 35000 too big?
Alternatively use an array of bigint with struct { _BitInt(__BITINT_MAXWIDTH__) digit[69430/__BITINT_MAXWIDTH__ + 1]; }.
Or skip the whole bigint and use struct { unsigned digit[69430/UINT_WIDTH + 1]; }.
In all cases, we need to form supporting addition and print routines.

Fib(99999) --> about a 69,430 bit number. ref
So let us fix some problems first.
Enable all compiler warnings to get rapid feedback
Bit width
typedef unsigned _BitInt(65535) u65535; may not be big enough, so use an assert to test. @David Ranieri
If 69430 <= __BITINT_MAXWIDTH__ or so, we should be able to handle it with bitint.
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
static_assert((69430 + 10) < __BITINT_MAXWIDTH__, "Too big");

// typedef unsigned _BitInt(65535) u65535;
typedef unsigned _BitInt(69440) u65535;  // Let us use a few extra bits.

Format
"%u" is for printing an unsigned, not a unsigned _BitInt(something big).  Review fprintf() for the correct specifier.  (I'll comment below the specifier after a few days.)
printf("fib: %u\n", a);  // Wrong format


Leave it to OP to research and implement changes.  I was adverse to providing a copy/paste answer for this learner question.

From an algorithmic perspective, it is possible to create a concise sum function using two strings that represent large integers. Since each character is a digit, the strings can contain up to millions digits. Here is my example code. I tested calculating the 99,999th Fibonacci number is somewhat slow, taking approximately 5 seconds.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_DIGITS 100000

void addStrings(const char *a, const char *b, char *result) {
    int carry = 0, sum = 0;
    size_t lenA = strlen(a);
    size_t lenB = strlen(b);
    size_t maxSize = lenA > lenB ? lenA : lenB;
    size_t k = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < maxSize || carry; ++i) {
        sum = carry;
        if (i < lenA) sum += a[lenA - 1 - i] - '0';
        if (i < lenB) sum += b[lenB - 1 - i] - '0';
        result[k++] = sum % 10 + '0';
        carry = sum / 10;
    }
    result[k] = '\0';

    result = strrev(result);
}

int main() {
    char a[MAX_DIGITS] = "0";
    char b[MAX_DIGITS] = "1";
    char c[MAX_DIGITS];

    for (int i = 2; i <= 99999; ++i) {
        addStrings(a, b, c);
        strcpy(a, b);
        strcpy(b, c);
    }
    printf("%s", b);
    return 0;
}

I am uncertain whether this response fulfills your requirements. However, I welcome any feedback or comments you may have.

Why waste space by storing base 10 digits? You're using a byte that can hold 256 values to only use 10 of them. Summing would get easier too.

Thank you, I will revise and update answer accordingly.

@alexisrdt because it's easier to output a decimal result. In my bigint I sometimes use a radix of 10^9 for that reason.

@WeatherVane then convert it / generate the decimal representation when you actually need it, especially if it's just for one print statement at the end of all the computations.

@alexisrdt but then you need to introduce more bigint functions beyond the simple addition.

@alexisrdt Why buy your child a tricycle, when they're eventually going to want a Ferrari?  To someone who has never thought about implementing arbitrary-precision arithmetic, introducing them to it using arrays of simple base-10 digits is an excellent first way to start.
